# UK Marriage Visitor Visa application sending

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I am applying for a UK Marriage Visa from Atlanta,Ga in the USA. Do I have to use VFS Global to send my application or can i just use like fed ex or ups m very confused on how to send my application, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

VFS Global is not a courier service, it is the company that processes your application, meaning they carry out "administrative and non-discretionary tasks" related to your application.

You can mail your documents to them by any means you like.

The "fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label" that you are required to send for your visa to be returned can also be from any company.

Here is the web page: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Comment: It is often commented here that VFS is "just a glorified courier service", though. Of course that is figurative and doesn't mean that you can substitute a different "courier service" of your choice, but I think it would improve this answer to detail a bit more what "processes your application" actually entails. Surely, unless I'm misunderstanding something quite fundamental, they're not involved in either _deciding_ who gets a visa and who doesn't, _nor_ in the actual printing of physical visa stickers ...

Comment: The point I am trying to convey is that VFS is not a courier company, where you call them and they pick up your application package and take it to someone else who opens it and processes it. They receive your application package (which you can mail in any way you want), open it, check everything is in order, and then (if everything is in order) pass it to an official who will make an actual decision.

Comment: On the Visa website it says "To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label (we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills). Put your return shipping label and envelope inside the package, and keep a copy of the waybill for your records." Does this mean I have to get a shipping label through VFS or can I use nother company for shipping.

Comment: @HenningMakholm from questions on this site, though, it appears that VFS and similar companies do unfortunately have some control over who gets a visa and who doesn't, because of their gatekeeper function.  That is, they can decide that an application does not meet the requirements to be forwarded to the consulate even if it does.  This can arise from incorrect instructions on the part of the consulate or from the misinterpretation of correct instructions from the consulate.

Comment: @OFFSIDES you cannot get a shipping label through VFS.  You should select the shipping company of your choice (avoiding ground services and companies that offer only non-electronic waybills).

Comment: Its so confusing because there is a hyperlink on the  "prepaid electronic shipping label" that takes me to the VFS website why?

Comment: @OFFSIDES please [edit your question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/131269/edit) to add this information.  Please include a link to the page you're asking about.  Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa                                                                                                
                                      3.1 Return shipping
To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed (prepaid electronic shipping label)hyperlink

Comment: @OFFSIDES The hyperlink requires a login, so we cannot see it.